# How can CountIf accept a structured reference column as criteria VBA-wise?

Tags: excel, vba, parameters, countif

I'm trying to use structured references to the current columns the same as CountIf does for my UDF function. While

> =COUNTIF(Data[Team];Overview[Team])

works, my new function

> =CONCATENATEIF(Data[Team];Overview[Team];Data[Data])

doesn't work, since the Overview[Team] criteria Range can't be cast to a single value which is [#This Row].

I tried to change the parameter "criteria" As String as well as different methods. Calling

> =CONCATENATEIF(Data[Team];Overview[@Team];Data[Data])

with "@" works as intended. But CountIf can handle [@Team], [Team] and normal ranges like [A1:A4]. So how they do it?

```
Public Function CONCATENATEIF(check_range As Range, criteria As Range, data_range As Range) As Variant
    Dim mydic As Object
    Dim L As Long
    Set mydic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    For L = 1 To check_range.Count
        If check_range(L) = criteria Then
            mydic(L) = data_range(L)
        End If
    Next
    CONCATENATEIF= Join(mydic.items, ", ")
End Function
```

What cast does criteria need to work like CountIf's criteria? How can i transform the structured Reference [Team] to [@Team] vba-wise, so it selects the same row, where the Formular is used later.

[The table for the problem (sadly can't embed images yet)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zE1Q6.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

COUNTIF works due to **inferred reference**¹.

If you put a bunch of values in column A and then use `=INDEX(A:A, , )` (*Index(<column_A>, <all_rows>, <all_columns>)*) in an unused column to the right of the data then the result will be from the common row in column A. Since you haven't provided a specific row reference where a single cell reference is expected, the associated (or *inferred*) row is used. This is why COUNTIF works; it is using an inferred reference from the `Overview[Team]` column to reference a single cell for criteria; e.g. the cell in `Overview[Team]` that is on the same row as the formula (also known as `Overview[@Team]`).

The VBA code is not using an inferred reference. It is referencing the whole column of `Overview[Team]` where it needs a single cell for criteria (e.g. `Overview[@Team]`).

You could try to artificially parse the column of criteria down to a single cell with something like `Application.Caller.Row` or you could just use `Overview[@Team]` as the criteria like it was intended.

---

¹ <sub>I hope I got that term right. I use it so little that I have a hard time remembering the correct term sometimes.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i didn't try your way out yet, but it helps me a lot. Is there any reference guide for inferred references? The term is pretty new for me, so i want to read a little more about it. Since i can't find any source code for the native CountIf function, i would like to see how others did this, but i don't know where to look for it.

Comment: It's one of those things that doesn't get a lot of attention and as stated, I'm not 100% sure I got the term correct. If fact, I consider it 'lazy' formula writing when used in a worksheet function. In the UDF you could use `Set criteria = Intersect(Application.Caller.EntireRow, criteria)` before the loop. This is for all intents and purposes what a worksheet formul's inferred reference does.

Comment: `Intersect(Application.Caller.EntireRow, criteria)` works flawless! Thanks a lot. The question is solved with this.